# EFCore 7 issue using scaffold-dbcontext doesnt create hasone correctly

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I have a database with the following tables and the foreign keys are setup correctly:

```
ProjectUser (PK is ProjectId & UserId):
ProjectUserMember (PK is ProjectId, UserId, EmployeeId)
ProjectUserEquipment (PK is ProjectId, UserId, EquipmentId)
Employee (PK is EmployeeId)
Equipment (PK is EquipmentId)
Project (PK is ProjectId)
User (PK is UserId)
```

I am getting an error on the entity.HasOne() which is obviously incorrect and it also generates the code linking to Employee and Equipment tables which also is out of place.

The dbcontext that gets generated using scaffold is:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectUser>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(e => new { e.ProjectId, e.UserId });

    entity.ToTable("ProjectUser");

    entity.HasOne()
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.ProjectId)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_ProjectUser_Project");

    entity.HasOne()
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_ProjectUser_User");

    entity.HasMany(d => d.Employees)
        .WithMany(p => p.ProjectUsers)
        .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>(
            "ProjectUserMember",
            l => l.HasOne<Employee>().WithMany().HasForeignKey("EmployeeId").OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull).HasConstraintName("FK_ProjectUserMember_Employee"),
            r => r.HasOne<ProjectUser>().WithMany().HasForeignKey("ProjectId", "UserId").HasConstraintName("FK_ProjectUserMember_ProjectUser"),
            j =>
            {
                j.HasKey("ProjectId", "UserId", "EmployeeId");

                j.ToTable("ProjectUserMember");
            });

    entity.HasMany(d => d.Equipment)
        .WithMany(p => p.ProjectUsers)
        .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>(
            "ProjectUserEquipment",
            l => l.HasOne<Equipment>().WithMany().HasForeignKey("EquipmentId").OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull).HasConstraintName("FK_ProjectUserEquipment_Equipment"),
            r => r.HasOne<ProjectUser>().WithMany().HasForeignKey("ProjectId", "UserId").HasConstraintName("FK_ProjectUserEquipment_ProjectUser"),
            j =>
            {
                j.HasKey("ProjectId", "UserId", "EquipmentId");

                j.ToTable("ProjectUserEquipment");
            });
});
```

Previous versions of EF generated the following for ProjectUser:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectUser>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => new { e.ProjectId, e.UserId });

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Project)
                    .WithMany(p => p.ProjectUser)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.ProjectId)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_ProjectUser_Project");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.User)
                    .WithMany(p => p.ProjectUser)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_ProjectUser_User");
            });
```

Can anyone explain what would cause this. Previously generated code was using .NET Core 3.0.

Comment: Most likely a bug. Such issues should be reported/asked on their GitHub issue tracker.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem should be reported on the product's site.